# Xubuntu 12.4 upgraded fine but there are everywhere pale grey windows/menus with white fonts!

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

I upgraded to Xubuntu 12.4 through the update manager. Everything works fine except that many windows and menus (Ubuntu Software Center,Transmission properties etc) apear in pale grey with white fonts. For examle, it's impossible to read n change properties on Transmission. Titles apear excellently, the rest is really hard to read: white text on allmost white background ...
I have tried already:rebooting, changing theme/apearance
photo1 http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/-26042012-102025.php
When login as guest everything works fine.
I created a new account, all is fine 
photo2 http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/-26042012-103258.php
But I still want my initiall user-account which i had so well tuned...

Comment: Hi - can you add a link to a screenshot?  Also  - test if this is user specific by creating another user and logging in with that user.  Add any replies as edits to your question.  thanks.

Comment: What happens if you create a new user?

Comment: an educated guess is the one of the XFCE4 files in `~/.config/xfce4` causes your issue.  Perhaps tar and dropbox the contents of this folder & subfolders to allow someone to try and reproduce this?  Alternatively, rename the folder and login to get a clean desktop that you can retheme?

Comment: rename ...say     .config/blabl     ?

Comment: ... ok - dropped an answer for you to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a lot of people (myself included) are having this issue.  It seems to be an issue with a couple of the appearance themes.  I found that by switching to Albatross to graybird, the problem went away.  Looks like it may be an issue with the Albatross (and few other) theme.

Here is the bug report:

[Theme Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shimmer-themes/+bug/989814)

Comment: Thanks for the bug report Preston! The solution offered there solved my issue; the exact same issue reported by Costa.

Comment: thanx - that did the trick for me: i had a similar problem that was not session-related (it persisted in lubuntu and xubuntu) but theme related as you say. but Costa's question seemed related to sessions

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would effectively reset your XFCE configuration for your account.  You can then retheme this.

Boot to the login window - do not login.

Move to a TTY1 - i.e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Login to your account.

rename your xfce config folder

```
mv ~/.config/xfce4 ~/.config/xfce4_backup
```

logout

Move to a TTY8 - i.e <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

This should display your GUI login screen.  Login as normal.  This should regenerate a new `~/.config/xfce4` folder structure with the defaults.

Comment: Note - if this does work, you'll still have your configuration files, and you can move the back over (IE from `.config/xfce4_backup` to `.config/xfce4`) one at a time to figure out which one is causing the error.  That way you don't lose your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple renaming of .config/xfc4....Look! this is too complicated for me!
Changing themes was  not my solution...
So I backed up my stuff, wrote my brand new isoCD of XUBUNTU12.4 and REinstalled everything! Now I celebrate my Xubuntu BUT What surprises me is that this time it got faster! that is faster than when upgraded from SoftwareCenter!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Preston's link to a workaround, there is now a small piece on the official Xubuntu FAQ page on this issue: http://xubuntu.org/news/faq-1204-precise/